# Does なぜ's pitch ever change in embedded questions?

Tags: pitch-accent

I have always heard なぜ{HL}, but [this one](https://youtu.be/ul9amfar8Jw?t=34) sounds like なぜ{LH} in 英語ベースの英語学習がなぜ間違ってるかというと. Am I mishearing it? I think most people say なぜ{HL} in both independent interrogative clauses and embedded questions, so this one throws me for a loop.